# Select specific layers from a WMS using URL link

Tags: wms, arcgis-online

I have a WMS from the Scottish Natural heritage which contains multiple layers:

https://cagmap.snh.gov.uk/arcgis/services/snh_habitats_and_species/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS

I am wanting to put this as a service into ArcGIS Online, but I only want one layer imported from the service. The layer is “Special Areas of Conservation” I understand that you can add GetRequests into the above link to select the layers, but I cannot get it to work.

I have tried putting the WMS into QGIS, and I can see all the layers, but I cannot get the URL for just the one layer I need.

Can anyone help? I know its probably quite simple and its been frustrating me for a few hours.

Comment: Just add: &layers=layername  to your URL. Do you use the exact layername out of the GetCapabilities-document? Often the name shown in the GUI is not the one used in the background.

Comment: Cascade it through another WMS

Comment: @matte it should be layers=layername&, the WMS specification tells us that the & closes the key=value pair

Comment: You are correct. I was simplifying it for copying it at the end. The last closing "&" can be left, which is the case in the given example. To add another parameter you have to add the "&" to close the "service=WMS" before you start the next one.

Comment: @matte it's only optional on WMS 1.3.0.  For a GetCapabilities request without version, ss you should add it, as you don't know which versions are supported; sorry in pedant mode.   I can't see though how you add a layers parameter to a GetCapabilites request at all though.

Comment: And again... You are correct :) . I was somehow thinking as if this was the GetMap request. Somewhere around 35°C you shouldn´t answer detailed questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that you can add GetRequests into the above link to select the layers, but I cannot get it to work.

You can't add any more Get requests into that URL, the request is already an HTTP GET request and the WMS request type is `GetCapabilities`.

If you look at the XML response for that link you can see it is telling you (or the your client i.e. QGIS) that there are request types available (other than GetCapabilities) like GetMap and GetFeatureInfo.

So for QGIS you should give the URL:

`https://cagmap.snh.gov.uk/arcgis/services/snh_habitats_and_species/MapServer/WMSServer?`

and from that stem it will create the appropriate request like a GetMap request to give a map, and a GetFeatureInfo request to get the attribute value of the data in a map.

You say that:

> I only want one layer imported from the service. The layer is “Special Areas of Conservation”

I can't actually see a layer of that name at all

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/communicating-with-a-wms-service-in-a-web-browser.htm

Also I tried to use the service you mentioned and formatted the request:

https://cagmap.snh.gov.uk/arcgis/services/snh_habitats_and_species/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.1.1&request=GetFeatureInfo&layers=0&styles=default&SRS=EPSG:4326&bbox=54.60551407420393,-8.176656137274902,60.831349952320146,-0.7698078063274678&width=1044&height=906&format=text/html&X=500&Y=400&query_layers=0

But you may have to tinker with the above formatted WMs request.